# Ubuntu is slow And freeze

Tags: ubuntu

[image]I have a computer (Asus gl552vw) with 
Processor : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700HQ CPU @ 2.60GH
8 Ram
But still really slow and freezes very often [image]

Since i'm a programmer i need to work with Applications like Eclipse and Android Studio while i'm surfing on the internet under google chrome I really need your help, thank you !!!

Edit : THis is the result of the comands
 dmseg and grep -i -e temp -e therm /var/log/syslog*

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLD10.png)

[image]

Comment: Check the log files at the point of the freeze and you will mostly find the answer there

Comment: @MunzirTaha I guess my computer (Cpu) is overheating for no reason

Comment: I'm not so sure about that. If you read this closely, it seems that in the end temperature is 50C (normal). @kiratsunami please try to run command sensors.

Comment: @kiratsunami: these are not relevant. Better launch `dmesg -w` in one terminal and when you had a freeze, check the the messages there and paste it all somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess but review network config, especially /etc/hosts. It should look more or less like in the example here:

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/hosts.5.html

If hosts file is not pointing correctly to your computer, you will experience unexplained sluggishness from most of the applications.

Answer (score 0):

@mkkot

I guess it's the same

Ty for your help

[image]